# Finding longest consecutive sequence of a character

Tags: python, regex

Assume we have a string like `'w q a a a a a e d a a'`, I would like to find the longest sequence of `'a'` with length of at least 2, which is `'a a a a a'` in the above example. I tried the following:

```
re.findall(r'(a a a*)', text)
```

but it only gives the shortest possible match. Then I tried:

```
re.findall(r'([^a] a a a* [^a])', text)
```

but the results for the above example string is empty. How can I do that?

Comment: You mean like `(?:a ){2,}` ("*`a` followed by a space, at least twice but as many times as possible"*)? See e.g. https://regex101.com/r/rL3lY4/1

Comment: Oooh man, thanks. That is what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have space between you `a` character. You can use a character class which match any combination of `a` and space with length 5 or more:

```
>>> re.findall(r'([a ]{5,})', text)
[' a a a a a ']
```

Also note that you don't need a capture group around the whole of your regex, In that case you can use a none-capture group with `a` and space (to refuse of matching the short pattern) and since you just want one match you can use `re.search()`:

```
>>> M = re.search(r'(?:a ){2,}', text)
>>> 
>>> M.group(0)
'a a a a a '
```